# iTunes updated my iPhone 5c to 9.1 but now iTunes on my PC wont connect to my phone

Tags: iphone

I have updated my iPhone 5c to iOS 9.1
When I try to connect it to my iTunes Library I get a message that the iPhone can't be used as it requires a newer version of iTunes.

iPhone and iTunes are both up to date.

I'm using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of iTunes is unlikely to be up to date [currently 12.3.1], as the latest version requires a minimum OS of Windows 7.

Your only real solution would appear to be to upgrade your OS.

> Windows System Requirements
>
> Hardware:
>
> - PC with a 1GHz Intel or AMD processor with support for SSE2 and 512MB of RAM
> - To play standard definition video from the iTunes Store, an Intel Pentium D or faster processor, 512MB of RAM and a DirectX 9.0-compatible video card are required.
> - To play 720p HD video, an iTunes LP or iTunes Extras, a 2.0GHz Intel Core 2 Duo or faster processor, 1GB of RAM and an Intel GMA X3000, ATI Radeon X1300 or NVIDIA GeForce 6150 or better are required.
> - To play 1080p HD video, a 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo or faster processor, 2GB of RAM and an Intel GMA X4500HD, ATI Radeon HD 2400 or Nvidia GeForce 8300 GS or better are required.
> - Screen resolution of 1024x768 or greater; 1280x800 or greater is required to play an iTunes LP or iTunes Extras
> - 16-bit sound card and speakers
> - Broadband Internet connection to use Apple Music, the iTunes Store and iTunes Extras
> - iTunes-compatible CD or DVD recorder to create audio CDs, MP3 CDs, or back-up CDs or DVDs. Songs from the Apple Music catalogue cannot be burned to a CD.
>
> Software:
>
> - Windows 7 or later
> - 64-bit editions of Windows 7 and Windows 8 require the iTunes 64-bit installer; for more information, visit www.itunes.com/download
> - 400MB of available disk space
> - Screen reader support requires Window-Eyes 7.2 or later; for information about accessibility in iTunes, visit www.apple.com/accessibility
> - iTunes is now a 64-bit application on 64-bit versions of Windows 8 and 7. Some third-party visualisers may no longer be compatible with this version of iTunes. Please contact the developer for an updated visualiser that is compatible with iTunes 12.1 or later
> - Apple Music, Apple Music Radio, iTunes in the Cloud and iTunes Match availability may vary by country

Source: http://www.apple.com/uk/itunes/download/